# How to compare the number of delimiters across a unix file to be matching with the top row(fields)?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, text-processing

I am setting up a var as

```
var=$(cat ip.txt | head -1 | sed 's/[^|]//g' | awk '{ print length }')
```

which stores the number of `'|'` in the top row.

Then, I can get the number of delimiters in each line using

```
awk -F\| '{print NF-1}' ip.txt
```

and I need to compare the individual numbers that I get with `$var`.

Final Output required is the number of lines which show such a behaviour. 
For example, if line 2 to line 20 have more delimiters than the header, then my output should be, 19 lines have greater number of delimiters than the top row from a total of 6000 rows(number of rows in the file).

Example :

```
$ cat ip.txt
DeptID|EmpFName|EmpLName|Salary
Engg|Sam|Lewis|1000
Engg|Smith|Davis|2000|||
HR|Denis|Lillie|1500
HR|Danny|Borrinson|3000|
IT|David|Letterman|2000||
IT|John|Newman|3000
```

The header has 3 '|', but lines 3,5 and 6 have extra delimiters.
so I want an output like "3 lines have more delimiters than the top row from a total of 7 rows"

Comment: Provide an actual input sample and expected output.

Comment: Edited the question with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F '|' '
 NR == 1 {
    # take the reference of field
    RefCount = NF - 1
    # skip header
    next
    }
 {
 # count the number of line having NF - 1 separator in an array (1 count by number of separator)
 LinesWith[ (NF - 1)] ++ 
 # uncomment line after if you want to print bad lines
 # if ( NF - 1 != RefCount) print 
 }

 # at the end (of file)
 END {
    # print each element of the counting array (bad first, good finally)
    for ( LineWith in LinesWith) if ( LineWith != RefCount) print "There is/are " LinesWith[ LineWith] " line(s) with " LineWith  " separators"
     print "There is/are " LinesWith[ RefCount] " correct line(s) with " RefCount " separators"
     }
  ' ip.txt
```

**Comment:**

- This is not a oneliner ("could be") but use only 1 awk to do everything except that there is no varaible assigned for the script if needed after.
- Code is self commented for understanding used concept (so seems a bit long)
- I change a bit the request (count each specific separator) but some simple modification could give the amount instead of detail

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR==1{n=NF} NF>n{c++} END{printf "%d lines > %d fields\n", c, NR}' ip.txt
3 lines > 7 fields
```

Comment: As ever, simple and precise ^, got my answer downvoted though, was able to achieve it too!

Comment: This is helpful. Although, can there be an enhancement for this? I need to delete the lines where the number of delimiters are greater than the header. The above case should delete the 3 lines.

Comment: Why would you ask for an enhancement to the answer you didn't accept rather than the one you did? In any case this question has been closed for 3 months already, you'd be better off asking a new question rather than expecting ongoing support for this one.